# Property 'mesh' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I follow the documentation of React Three Fiber but get stuck in this issue.

Here is my component
[image]

And dependencies

[image]

Comment: you should add your code in question not just an image of it read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found out the reason for this issue.

I'm using the version 8 of `@react-three/fiber` and `Vitejs`, so I have to `extend` manually

```js
import { extend} from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Mesh, BoxGeometry, MeshStandardMaterial } from 'three'

extend({ Mesh, BoxGeometry, MeshStandardMaterial })
```

refer this:
https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/canvas#tree-shaking